# Where can I find a real dataset anywhere online that I could try doing a data warehouse cube with?

Tags: data-warehouse

I am studying data warehouses and I have to do one final project for my studies.

I am thinking about doing a cube for a data warehouse. Where can I find a real dataset anywhere online that I could try doing a cube with?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this page to see how to convert a part of the Northwind database to a star schema for building cubes: [Northwind Star Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140038(office.10).aspx#odc_da_whatrcubes_topic2).

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an example on Adventure Works](http://techpunch.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/sql-server-2008-how-to-build-and-deploy-adventureworks-olap-cubes/) - of course, it's prebuilt SSAS, but I guess you could look at the underlying AventureWorks DB and do the dimensional modeling yourself.

I think doing a DW on an existing popular dataset like Northwind or AdventureWorks is probably not a great idea, because so many people have done them.  Even StackOverflow has [had data mining done](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/06/data-mining-the-stackoverflow-database/), but perhaps it would be a good candidate - I'm not sure what Brent's work actually comprised.

So if you are looking to do an original project, you might need to look further afield, if only to distinguish your work from previous work.